# Vue 2 directiva :src no muestra imagen pero carga HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html, laravel, vue.js

Estoy creando esta aplicación con Laravel 5.4 y Vue 2 y necesito mostrar una imagen si está o no presente. Para esto utilicé las directivas `v-if` y `v-else`.

Para empezar éste es mi código JS:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        term: "",
        category: "",
        ads: []
    },
    mounted: function() {
        var self = this;
            axios.get('{{ url('/api/avisos/get') }}')
            .then(function(response) {
                self.ads = response.data;
            });
    },
    methods: {
        loadAds: function() {
            var self = this;
            axios.get('{{ url('/api/avisos/get') }}', {
                params: {
                    term: this.term,
                    category: this.category
                }
            }).then(function(response) {
                self.ads = response.data;
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.log('Error: ' + error);
            });
        },
        submitForm: function() {
            if(this.term != '' || this.category != '') {
                this.loadAds();
            }
        },
    }
});
```

Y gracias a Bootstrap 4 uso tarjetas y renderizo la información:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="card" style="width: 20rem; margin-left:1rem;" v-for="ad in ads" v-cloak>
      <img v-if="ad.image1" class="card-img-top" :src="'/public/images/ads/' + ad.image1" alt="Imagen">
      <img v-else class="card-img-top" src="/public/images/logo.png" alt="No Imagen">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">@{{ ad.title }}</h4>
        <p class="card-text">
            @{{ ad.description }}<br><hr>
            <strong>$@{{ ad.cost }}</strong>
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Contactar con vendedor</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Todo funciona a la perfección, excepto que las imágenes son mostradas en el HTML pero no en la práctica:

[image: Imagen no carga]

Si yo copia esa misma URL y la pego en el navegador, me muestra la imagen perfectamente.

He probado usar `v-show` en vez de `v-if` y `v-attr="src: link"` o `v-bind:src="link"` en vez de `:src` pero no hay caso.

¿Alguna idea de qué está pasando y cómo solucionar esto?

Gracias!

**Edito**:

Lo más loco de todo es que las imágenes se muestran perfectamente en Microsoft Edge y Google Chrome mobile, no funciona en Firefox ni Google Chrome, ni **Internet Explorer** (en IE ni siquiera se muestran los avisos por un error:

> [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: 'Promise' no está definido"

Comment: estas segura que la URL es la misma al abrir en el navegador y no existe un redireccionamiento al abrir la imagen en una ventana del navegador?, puedes publicar la URL que te abre  al copiar la URL?

Comment: Utiliza la url completa en lugar de usar la relativa, porque esta añadiendo esa ruta a partir del directorio actual y no desde la raíz.

Comment: Ya intenté eso Xerif y no funcionó. 
Por otro lado @GuillermoAndresFuentesMoral estoy seguro porque lo he probado, sería información incorrecta que di.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el problema debe ser que tenes que agregarle tu dominio a las url.

Yo uso los Vue components y varía un poco, pero dentro de un componente una de las formas de solucionar eso es:

1- Agregar en la vista principal en el head lo siguiente

```
<script>
  window.App = { host: '{{ url("/") }}/' }
</script>
```

2- En la imagen llamas a la variable App

Otra opcion (como trabajas directo en la vista) es utilizar el helper directamente.

```
:src="'{{ url("/") }}/public/images/ads/' + ad.image1"
```

Espero haberte sido de ayuda.

Saludos

Maru

Answer (score -1):

El problema es Axios cuando te manda la promesa no puedes usar el this ya no te servirá.

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        term: "",
        category: "",
        ads: []
    },
    mounted: function() {
            axios.get('{{ url('/api/avisos/get') }}')
            .then(function(response) {
                vm.ads = response.data;
            });
    },
    methods: {
        loadAds: function() {
            var self = this;
            axios.get('{{ url('/api/avisos/get') }}', {
                params: {
                    term: this.term,
                    category: this.category
                }
            }).then(function(response) {
                vm.ads = response.data;
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.log('Error: ' + error);
            });
        },
        submitForm: function() {
            if(this.term != '' || this.category != '') {
                this.loadAds();
            }
        },
    }
});
```

Comment: Hola @yoe-anonimo, por favor revisa las recomendacicones de la comunidad en [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).