# Vue no muestra los datos en la vista

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

Tengo una pequeña api realizada en Laravel, está funcionando sin problemas y todas las pruebas en Postman son exitosas, el problema es cuando intento mostrar los datos por la vista Vue, simplemente no me muestra nada, ni siquiera errores

Este es el código de la vista

```
<template>
    <div id="home" class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
           <div class="col-md-8">
               <div class="card card-default" v-for="product in products" 
                  :key="product.id">
                    <div class="card-header">{{product.name}}</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                         {{product.totalPrice}}
                    </div>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
   export default {
      data() {
          return {
              products: [],
          }
      },
      created(){
          this.allProducts();
      },
      methods: {
        allProducts(){
            let self = this;
            let urlAllProducts = '/api/products';
            axios.get(urlAllProducts)
                .then(response => {
                    self.products = response.data;
                })
                .catch(err => {

                })
          }
      },
   }
 </script>
```

ProductController

```
public function index()
{
    return ProductCollection::collection(Product::all());
}
```

Archivo Api.php

```
Route::apiResource('/products', 'ProductController');
Route::group(['prefix' => 'products'], function(){
    Route::apiResource('/{product}/reviews','ReviewController');
});
```

La vista se ve así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy un par de horas ya metido con este problema.

¿Alguna idea? ocupo Laravel 5.6, Vuejs 2

Comment: por que declaras self.products = response.data? debería ser this.products = response.data

Comment: Según lo que veo no estas recibiendo nada de la API, podrías mostrar el log de la respuesta?

Comment: yo trabajo sin problema this.products = response.data

Comment: @AlfredoPaz, con this tampoco funciona y la API trae los datos ya que con un console.log los muestra, si solamente en la vista pongo {{product} me muestra el array

Comment: @AlfredoPaz, con this tampoco funciona y la API trae los datos ya que con un console.log los muestra, si solamente en la vista pongo {{product} me muestra el array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me estaría faltando ver el código de la vista y la respuesta que estás obteniendo al hacer la llamada a la api desde el componente, pero en base a mi experiencia creo que tenés 2 opciones:

**1-** Si estás usando el componente en una vista de blade no necesitás tener un método de consulta a la api para obtener los productos, le mandas el array al componente y listo **(tendría que ver la vista)**

***Ejemplo en vista blade:***

```
<all-products :products="{{$products}}"/>
```

**2-** En el caso de que no estés enviando a la vista el listado de productos deberías hacer la llamada a la api con su url absoluta. Mirá esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/97392/57312)
También podrías definir una variable `url` en el componente y pasarle la url desde la vista y ahí usar el método para obtener los productos.
***Ejemplo:***
**En componente vue**

```
<script>
   export default {
      data() {
          return {
              products: [],
              url: '', // también lo podes pasar como props
          }
      },
      created(){
          this.allProducts();
      },
      methods: {
        allProducts(){
            let self = this;
            let urlAllProducts = this.url + '/api/products';
            axios.get(urlAllProducts)
                .then(response => {
                    self.products = response.data;
                })
                .catch(err => {

                })
          }
      },
   }
 </script>
```

**En vista Blade**

```
<all-products :url="{{url('/'}}"/>
```