# ¿Se puede Pasar un array a un componente vue?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, component

Tengo una duda.

En una determinada vista de laravel cargo ciertos datos los cuales atravez de mi controlador se los paso con (Compact) y ya posteriormente se cargan  y los muestro con mi foreach . 
pero  No sé si hay alguna forma de poder pasar ese  array a mi componente de  vue

---

De hecho lo había podido implementar con  una APi Que me carga mi lista de Productos como ejemplo, pero Tengo una duda respecto a mi Api. Pues resulta ser algo insegura y no sé como puedo hacer para que nadie más le haga peticiones(osea solo las peticiones provengan de la misma pagina) Y que tampoco pueda ver el listado  Si accedo directamente a mi Apirest por ej. www.ejemplo.com/listaProductos

---

Mi controlador solo lo tengo de esta forma  Ej.  algo Corto.

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Producto;
class Ideacontroller extends Controller
{
    
      public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function getProductos()
    {

     return Producto::orderBy('id','DESC')->get(); 
    }

}
```

Comment: Claro que se puede, necesitarías colocar algo de codigo como para que podamos ayudar mejor.   Quizá esta respuesta te puede ayudar https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/161946/57312

Comment: Hola, Si de hecho lo he podido implementar con La api. pero es que no se como proteger mi api Para que nadie pueda hacerle peticiones o que no se pueda visualizar desde la apgina cuando acceda a ella directamente

Comment: esa es otra opción. Si no habilitas cors no deberían de poder acceder a tu api. Hacé la prueba desde postman u alguna otra app para ver que respuesta recibís

Comment: igualmente si estás usando un componente vue en una vista blade podrías enviarle data al componente desde el contolador o incluso desde un view composer

Comment: si de hecho en postman  me regresa toda la lista correctamente.

Comment: ¿como puedo Pasarl a mi componente vue?

Comment: Me está faltando data para ayudarte. Controlador que retorna la vista y la vista propiamente dicha en donde utilizas el componente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un ejemplo sencillo de como puedes obtener cualquier informacion que necesites en tus componentes, mediante Axios haciendo llamados a tu API o a cualquier API.

```html
<template>
    <li v-for="user in users" >
        {{user.firstName}}
    </li>

</template>

<script>
import $axios from 'axios'   
const BASE_URL='http://localhost:5000/api'

        
export default {
   data(){
    return{
      users:[]
    }
   }
   async getUsers(){
      const URL = `${BASE_URL}/users`
       try{
          const response=await $axios.get(URL).then(res=>res.data)           
          this.users=response             
       }catch(e){
            //do somenthing with errors
          console.error(e)
       } 
    
        
   }

}

</script>
```