# Select dependientes con ajax y laravel para un vista edit

Tags: ajax, laravel

Actualmente estoy trabajando en una vista edit `http://127.0.0.1:8000/dgj/editar_ejuridica/7`, tengo dos select dependientes `has('ciudad') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                    
                        *Ciudad:

```
                            @foreach($ciudades as $ciudad => $value)
                            <option value="{{$value->id}}">{{$value->city_cty}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('municipio') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">
                    *Municipio: 
                </label>
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <select class="form-control dynamic" id="municipio" name="municipio">
                        <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Municipios</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>`
```

Utilizo este código AJAX :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#ciudad').on('change', function(e){
    console.log(e);
    var ciudad_id = e.target.value;

    $.get('select_ciudad?ciudad_id=' + ciudad_id,function(data) {

      $('#municipio').empty();
      $('#municipio').append('<option value="0" disable="true" selected="true"></option>');

      $.each(data, function(fetch, regenciesObj){
        $('#municipio').append('<option value="'+ regenciesObj.id +'">'+ regenciesObj.municipality_mty +'</option>');
      })
    });
  });
```

la ruta para este AJAX es la siguiente:

```
Route::get('select_ciudad', 'SelectController@fetch')->name('dgj.vwempresas.fetch');
```

y este es mi controlador:

```
  class SelectController extends Controller
{
    function fetch(Request $request)
    {

      $ciudad_id = Input::get('ciudad_id');

      $regencies = Municipio::where('cityid_mty', '=', $ciudad_id)->get();
      return response()->json($regencies);  
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mis select son Ciudad y municipio, en la vista crear tengo lo mismo con el mismo script y el mismo controlador y funciona correctamente, en la vista edit que estoy trabajando no funciona

Answer (score 1):

Tuve el mismo problema que tu.  La solucion estaba en modificar adecuadamente las rutas.

En tu ajax modifica el .get de la siguiente manera:

```
<script type="text/javascript">$('#ciudad').on('change', function(e){
console.log(e);
var ciudad_id = e.target.value;

$.get('../select_ciudad/ciudad_id,function(data) {

  $('#municipio').empty();
  $('#municipio').append('<option value="0" disable="true" selected="true"></option>');

  $.each(data, function(fetch, regenciesObj){
    console.log(data);
    $('#municipio').append('<option value="'+ regenciesObj.id +'">'+ regenciesObj.municipality_mty +'</option>');
  })
});
```

y en tu route agrega el siguiente:

```
Route::get('/select_ciudad/{id}', 'SelectController@fetch')->name('dgj.vwempresas.fetch');
```

Answer (score 0):

el problema es que estás haciendo la consulta a

`http://127.0.0.1:8000`**`/dgj/editar_ejuridica/`**`select_ciudad`
            y tu ruta para consultas de municipio es
`http://127.0.0.1:8000`**`/`**`select_ciudad`.

El problema es porque estás enviando una ruta relativa y no a una ruta absoluta.
Pasale la url a la petición ajax

Podés Agregar en la vista principal (master template) en el head lo siguiente, de esta forma vas a tener la url disponible en todas tus vistas.

```
<script>
  window.App = { host: '{{ url("/") }}/' }
</script>
```

En la petición llamás a la variable App

**Otra opcion (si el script está en la vista) es utilizar el helper `url()`.**

```
  $('#ciudad').on('change', function(e){
    console.log(e);
    var ciudad_id = e.target.value;

    $.get({{ url("/") }}'/select_ciudad?ciudad_id=' + ciudad_id,function(data) {

      $('#municipio').empty();
      $('#municipio').append('<option value="0" disable="true" selected="true"></option>');

      $.each(data, function(fetch, regenciesObj){
        $('#municipio').append('<option value="'+ regenciesObj.id +'">'+ regenciesObj.municipality_mty +'</option>');
      })
    });
  });
```

Referencia: [Vue 2 directiva :src no muestra imagen pero carga HTML](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92937/vue-2-directiva-src-no-muestra-imagen-pero-carga-html/97392#97392)

Answer (score 0):

Hola @Maru gracias por tu respuesta, probé utilizar el helper url()
pero aun me da problemas, el select de municipio no me carga ningún data correspondiente a la ciudad seleccionada [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al código AJAX que tenia le agregue {{ url("/") }}, utilice el helper url() ya que el script lo tengo en la vista editar.

Asi es como tengo el código AJAX ahora:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $('#ciudad').on('change', function(e){
    console.log(e);
    var ciudad_id = e.target.value;

    $.get('{{ url("/") }}select_ciudad?ciudad_id=' + ciudad_id,function(data) {

      $('#municipio').empty();
      $('#municipio').append('<option value="0" disable="true" selected="true"></option>');

      $.each(data, function(fetch, regenciesObj){
        console.log(data);
        $('#municipio').append('<option value="'+ regenciesObj.id +'">'+ regenciesObj.municipality_mty +'</option>');
      })
    });
  });
```

Mi vista edit, la ruta y el controlar las deje igual pero a como se muestra en la imagen el combobox no me carga los datos de municipio.

Gracias de antemano por su ayuda.