# Ayuda para resolver error GET 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

Estoy tratando de crear un select dinámico con ajax, al seleccionar un rol, deben desplegarse los usuarios que tengan el rol seleccionado.

El script que estoy utilizando es el siguiente

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sucursal').on('change', function(e){
            console.log(e);

            var id = e.target.value;

            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: 'ajax'+id,
                scuccess: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Mi ruta está de la siguiente manera

```
Route::get('ajax/{id}', ['as'=>'ajax','uses'=>'RecepcionController@ajax']);
```

Y en mi controlador tengo lo siguiente

```
public function ajax($id) {
  $id    = $id;
  $nombre = User::where('role_id','=',$id)->get();
  return response()->json($nombre);
 }
```

Comment: tienes una c extra en `success`

Comment: Es verdad, pero aún sigue mostrando el mismo error.

Comment: Falta información, revisa el inspector de chrome, en "Network" para ver el mensaje de error que entrega Laravel, de lo contrario revisa su log.

Answer (score 1):

Deberias tratar de ponerle un / al ajax

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      url: 'ajax/'+ id,
      scuccess: function(data){
      console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Por lo general ese error ocurre cuando algo malo pasó en tu servidor. Deberías ir a ver que te está respondiendo la consola y la red, y si la respuesta viene en blanco activar la traza de errores en el PHP.
Le falta un slash a tu ruta, por como se comporta tu controlador

```
url: 'ajax/'+id,
```

> The 500 Internal Server Error is a very general HTTP status code that means something has gone wrong on the website's server, but the server could not be more specific on what the exact problem is.

```
error_reporting(-1);
```

o

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
```

[Habilitar errores PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Puede que sea diferente puesto que estás usando laravel

Comment: si coloco la ruta url: 'ajax/+id, se crea un error 404

Comment: en consola se muestra el siguiente error

Comment: yt.Event {originalEvent: Event, type: "change", isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, target: select#sucursal.form-control.input-sm, currentTarget: select#sucursal.form-control.input-sm, …}

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu problema es el mismo que en este caso [Select dependientes con ajax y laravel para un vista edit](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/161878/select-dependientes-con-ajax-y-laravel-para-un-vista-edit/161943#161943).

Estás haciendo la petición a una ruta relativa y deberías hacerla a una absoluta.

```
app_url: 'http://localhost:8000/';

$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: app_url + 'ajax/' + id,
    scuccess: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```